# Disable all Checkboxes in JStree

Tags: jquery, jstree

I am using jtree plugin in my application. I want to disable all checkboxes in jstree in edit mode. The checkbox is programmaticly checked after load jstree. my only thing is want to disable all checkboxes.

```
$("#testId").jstree({
            "json_data" : {              
                "data" : rootNode,
                "progressive_render" : true,
                "progressive_unload" : true

            },
             "checkbox" : {
        "two_state" : true
        },  
                "themes" : {
                "theme" : "apple",
                "dots" : false,
                "icons" : false
            },       
                "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "ui", "checkbox"]
       });
```

Comment: `if ($('input[type=checkbox']:checked).length) { } ` will check if atleast one checkbox is checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any uncheck code inside the

```
.bind("loaded.jstree",function(e,data){

//your jquery code for check and uncheck.

});
```

this will call the required action when the tree gets loaded.

If you encounter problems let me know.

Answer (score 2):

One more thing that might work for you would be,

You can programmaticly check and uncheck the required checkboxes based on the json data or javascript in the

```
.bind("loaded.jstree",function(e,data){

//your jquery code for check and uncheck.

});
```

later to disable checking and unchecking the jstree checkbox you can do the following:

```
.bind("check_node.jstree",function(e,data){
      return false;
});

.bind("uncheck_node.jstree",function(e,data){
      return false;
});
```

This will disallow user from changing the status of the checkbox.

I discovered this while experimenting!!!

Answer (score -1):

Demo [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sethuramanP/ay6SF/)

**Jquery**

```
$('.check').eq(4).prop('checked',true); //checkbox checked
if($('.check:checked').length>0)
    $('.check').attr('disabled','disabled');

$('.check1').eq(3).prop('checked',true);  //checkbox checked
if($('.check1:checked').length>0)
    $('.check1').not($('.check1').eq(4)).attr('disabled','disabled');
```

As per your condition you will change the class

Comment: Suggestion: Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

Comment: This answer is not related to JSTree. Also, JSTree does not use actual checkboxes. Instead, it renders checkboxes via <i> tags.